# Do i need a transit visa for Brussels

Tags: transit

I have a Kenyan passport. Do I need a visa to transit in Brussels?. I have an ongoing flight 5 hours after I land in Brussels.

Comment: An ongoing flight to where?

Comment: And while I'm asking, where's the incoming flight coming from?